# jquery get directory name of current path

Tags: jquery

I want to get the last directory of each urls below.. unfortunately theres something wrong on getting the outputs..

- localhost/myapp/app/my-directory-name-1/ = returns **my-directory-name-1**
- localhost/myapp/app/my-directory-name-2/index.php = returns **my-directory-name-2**
- localhost/myapp/app/my-directory-name= returns **app**

I used this code to get the last directory of the current url:

```
slug = window.location.pathname;
slug = slug.substring(0, slug.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
slug = slug.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1];
```

With the case 1, it returns the correct last directory..

With the case 2, it also returns the correct last directory..

But with the case 3, it returns the second to the last directory which is the /app..

Any help regarding to this? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: The problem with '/'. in your case 3 don't have '/'. So you need to validate that last part of the string and if it has any extension (ex: .php) then you have to previous one. else you have to take the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest you a different approach?

```
slug = window.location.pathname;
res = slug.split('/');
if ( res[res.length-1] == 'index.php' || res[res.length-1] == '' ){
    res.pop();
}
slug = res[res.length-1];
```